# Windows Phone nullable int binding doesn't work for TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Binding doesn't work if value is Nullable, but works like a charm if it isn't.

### XAML

```
   <TextBox 
       Text="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=''}" 
       InputScope="Number" 
       MaxLength="2"/>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: This? http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2008/07/09/binding-to-nullable-values-in-xaml.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Mikko pushed me to a solution. So, values must be returned from the converter in a destination type. `"23"` is not a valid `int?` and it is not converting automatically. You should do it by yourself.

In my particular case this converter helped me:

### Converter

```
public class NullableIntToString : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString())) return null;
        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result)) return result;

        return null;
    }
}
```

### XAML

```
   <...>

   <Page.Resources>
      <converters:NullableIntToString x:Key="NullableValue"/>
   </Page.Resources>

   <...>

   <TextBox 
      Text="{
         Binding Age, 
         Mode=TwoWay, 
         Converter={StaticResource NullableValue}
      }" 
      InputScope="Number" 
      MaxLength="2"/>

   <...>
```

Answer (score 0):

A [good reference](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/12/16/using-wpf-binding-stringformat-property-with-nullable-types/) of this behavior.

Instead of creating an converter, a quick solution is to use TargetNullValue and StringFormat 'D'

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Age,
               TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty},
               StringFormat=\{0:D\}}"
         InputScope="Number" />
```